# Process Monitor tracking registry events but doesn't show me the new values written in

Tags: windows-registry, process-monitor

I have Process Monitor showing me the events happening in my registry and what keys are being changed, but it doesn't show the changes themselves.  In other words, I's like it to show (in addition to what I already get) something like "new key value: 1" or whatever.

Is it able to do this?  How can I get it to?

Windows 7 home Premium 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProcMon should show you in the logs if you double click or hit enter on an entry, search for the Operations called "RegSetValue".

Comment: I needed to add the Details field to show.